# How to upload an icon in div(thumbnail) on button click with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

When user click on browse files. Need to select image from file system and display in the upload icon div

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and have you done any research? If so, please show us what you have so far.

Comment: function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.onload = function (e) {
     $('#blah')
     .attr('src', e.target.result)
     .width(150)
     .height(200);};

       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
}

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 ng-scope">
       <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
       <img class="image" id="blah" src="#" alt="Upload Icon"></img>

      </div>

Comment: @KarlC please look into the above code

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from this code

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```